Xero throwing exception "Where clause invocation error: Operations on optional fields must be preceded by a null guard, e.g. "[FieldName] != null""
Suddenly my Xero account throwing this exception with Existing Data when trying to get Invoice list
"Where clause invocation error: Operations on optional fields must be preceded by a null guard, e.g. "[FieldName] != null AND [FieldName]..."
Please help me on this.
I have create another dummy account and created multiple Invoices but looks those are fetching successfully.

Can you clarify what where clause you are using?

Passing these parameters into Xero API-
/api.xro/2.0/Invoices
where= (Status=="PAID" OR Status=="AUTHORISED") AND Date > DateTime.Parse("2024-11-25") AND Date < DateTime.Parse("2024-11-27")&unitdp=4

(Status=="PAID" OR Status=="AUTHORISED") AND Date > DateTime.Parse("2024-11-25") AND Date < DateTime.Parse("2024-11-27")"

@sallyhornet Please have a look on my above comment

Please can you raise with Xero Support using this link https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support and include the date and time of the most recent request in UTC and your app's client id
